# Questioner asking certain people not to answer

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, etiquette

In [this question (now deleted, see below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664915/rx-subscription-not-working-as-expected) OP signs-off with:

> I asked a similar question before, but not as well written as this. If you answered that one, please hold off on answering this one. I was not satisfied with or did not understand those answers. Thanks for understanding.

The question has an accepted answer now, but this sign-off is a little offensive and not useful.

I could simply edit it out and leave a comment, but just wanted to check if that was the appropriate course of action.

I feel like the user needs a little corrective note, and doing that publicly in comments could start a pointlessly "public exchange of views" in the question comments.

I wondered if I should flag it so that a moderator could send a private note, but I don't know if (a) this isn't a problem and I'm being a bit too "mother" (b) moderators even do that or (c) if it's overkill and just editing is fine.

Would appreciate advice so I can just do the right thing going forwards.

*Note on deletion:* After this post I noticed the question contained a link to a substantial amount of copyrighted material, which I flagged and the question was subsequently deleted.

Comment: just edit it out and leave a note, I wouldn't say it warrants moderator attention, unless he rolls it back and insists it stays. it's just noise and has no relevance to the question.

Comment: I wonder why the question has since been deleted?

Comment: After this was sorted, I subsequently discovered the OP had also linked in some copyrighted material. I flagged it and it was deleted. Although @bill-the-lizard I notice I can still access said material, it does really need to be obliterated.

Comment: Seems like the OP thinks this is his personal helpdesk. It is not.

Comment: @JamesWorld: it is only visible to 10+ users. It is not findable by any search engine. It is fine as it is. If the *copyright holder* has a problem with that state, they can always file a DMCA request to have it removed more thoroughly.

Comment: Ah OK, that's just my ignorance of how SO works showing through. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 10 **k** + !!!

Comment: @AmitJoki: yup, I managed to drop the `k`. Oops.

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete the question only because it contains a *link* to illegal content - the copyrighted material is not in the question itself, and the excerpt is properly cited. Imho the link should have deserved a simple edit as well.

Comment: Should have just closed as duplicate as "I asked a similar question before" - I don't see anything in the question that refers to original one and how new one is better/covers unclear parts of previous one. Something like "XXX answered previous one but I don't get YYY part of answer" would be much more constructive.

Comment: Wait @MartijnPieters, can I see deleted posts? I'm `rep>10`!

Comment: @k_g: He meant `10k`, as AmitJoki noted

Comment: @Bergi I realize that :-). I was just trying to embarrass a `>100k` into giving me a privilege (not the best strategy--I now realize)

Comment: @k_g: you need to squint at the screen at a 39.3218 degree angle, while singing the Marseillaise at 85 dB *exactly*, to see deleted posts with 10+ reputation. Oh, and don't forget to swing your shoes from your fingertips!

Comment: Regarding the copyrighted material, you could have just edited out the link instead of deleting the question. The bit of code copied into the question probably falls under fair use.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ...or replaced it with a link to [a legitimate source for the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ChJpGMFuAmUC).

Comment: @MarkRansom If the offending link were edited out or replaced, would it still be visible in the edit history? If so, is there a way for a moderator to excise things from the history?

Comment: That was the point I raised when I flagged, editing doesn't expunge the history, which is why I didn't do that.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I removed that section; meta talk has no place in a question anyway.

In the edit note I asked the OP not to do this:

> Copy edit, remove meta talk. Please don't dictate who can answer and who cannot.

If the user reverts or otherwise puts the info back in, I'd leave a comment explaining a bit more and if need be, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Good idea, using the edit summary... keeps it out of the more overt comments "channel".

Comment: @Martijn, Copyedit is one word.

Comment: @Pacerier: Either form, or even hyphenated, is valid.

Comment: @Pacerier: See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copy_edit, *copy edit* is valid too. Or *copy-edit*. There is no one spelling.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Not *yet*.

Comment: @Pacerier: according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing) using one word is far from winning. In the U.S. newspaper industry they appear to prefer the two-word form, while in the UK the hyphenated form is more common. Even the online dictionaries I sampled disagree on what form they list the entry under.

Comment: @Pacerier: personally, I was *editing copy*, I had performed an edit on the copy, or a *copy edit*. I'm not yet ready to concatenate the verb and the noun into a new verb here, nor do I think there is a pressing need to! :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters, According to [Wikipedia](http://goo.gl/4nF27s) using two words is more common *currently*, yet using one word will prevail sooner or later, just [not *yet*](http://goo.gl/xDs9a2). It's the [same situation](http://goo.gl/WKw05F) with "copywriting" vs "[copy writing](http://goo.gl/uXnNj1)". The original meaning of the words [will not matter](http://goo.gl/HJquZ0). Indeed, if "copyedit" was the original spelling, "copy edit" wouldn't even exist. It only works the other way round.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, And [per historical trends, there's completely no chance for the two-word version nor the hyphenated version to prevail](http://archive.is/WlrvV#selection-677.212-677.544); They are instead the ones that can be rightfully said to be "far from winning".  As long as there's a significant amount of authors writing an open compound or a hyphenated compound as a closed compound, **the trend can only go one way**: Who still  writes "email" as "e-mail"? "e-mail" looked silly; If it didn't, it looks silly now; If it doesn't, it'll look silly in the future.

Answer (score 26):

Personally I would have gone through the posters history, found his original post then flagged the new question as a duplicate of his first post and left it as that.

Comment: I would have done that too. And I would have explained that editing/clarifying the same question is better than opening a new one, since it avoids clogging up StackOverflow with duplicates and still brings the question back up to the top of the list for everyone to see (who might have missed it otherwise the first time around).

Comment: I did look and found no suitable dupe target. This question is more about the OP dictating who should answer and who cannot, I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

> I asked a similar question before, but not as well written as this.

I believe this already should be a red flag for a duplicate mark. The problem is  that there are exact same questions on SO asked over and over again and only one or two will have really good answer.

So my like in this particular case would first go to 1 - marking as a duplicate, 2 - pointing out that he/she should have instead edited original question.

But in general to the summary of this discussion - I strongly believe that such a remark (asking not to answer) is very inappropriate. If OP did not understand some answers he/she should have first checked if answerers understood what he/she have asked.

Comment: 1 - marking as a duplicate would have been difficult since the system requires to link to the original question. But I agree with your point #2, pointing out that he/she should have instead edited the original question, is a good idea since it tries to educate the user about how StackOverflow really works.